# Piping the output of one command as input to another command

Tags: c, pipe

I have the following assignment:

> Write a C program to read the names of two (or more) executable programs, and redirect the output of the first program to the input of the second program, output of the second program to the input of the third program, and so on...

I know at least the basics of piping in a shell. However, I don't understand how to implement this task in C using C pipes. I don't know how to take the output of one program as an input to another program and so on. Eg, in a shell:

```
ls | wc | ./add
```

Here `ls` list the files, `wc` gives the counts of the listed files, and `./add` adds the numbers given by `wc`.

Where do I start implementing piping in a C program?

Comment: Ah -- you would need to use the "pipe" function.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pipe.html

Comment: There's some example code on that page.  If you are still having a problem, please be more specific about where you get stuck.

Comment: Well, every `|` will need a pipe.  To start, you make a pipe, fork, in the child dup the write end onto stdout and exec ls.  Now fork again, in the child dup the read end onto stdin and exec wc.  Repeat as needed :)

Comment: @AhorConverse It's fine to ask about homework, but please say it's homework. People will make more of an effort to explain and help you work it out, not just give you an answer you might not understand. It looks like what you want is to write a program that does the shell's job, setting up a pipeline and executing it. Maybe you should look at how a simple shell like `dash` or `ash` does it? Don't even try to look at the `bash` source code.

Comment: See also this GitHub gist: [mplewis/threePipeDemo.c](https://gist.github.com/mplewis/5279108). The description says: _"Here's an example of how to pipe three commands together using C. This one uses `ps aux | grep root | grep sbin`. This topic is horribly documented online so hopefully this'll help someone else out."_ I found that link by doing a Google search for ["c pipe output of one command to another"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+pipe+output+of+one+command+to+another&oq=c+pipe+output+of+one+command+to+another&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.6928j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you need to create a program that does a simple case of the shell's job: creates and executes a pipeline of commands then outputs the result.

To do this right requires you to understand `SIGPIPE`, child process handling, input/output redirection, file descriptors, `fork()` and `exec()`, `wait()`, and more.

[This Linux Documentation Project article on creating pipelines](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) should help set you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pipe(pipefd)` to create a pipe, you get two file descriptors.  Whatever is written to `pipefd[1]` can be read from `pipefd[0]`.  So what you have to do is execute the first program such that its `stdout` is the same as `pipefd[1]`, and execute the second program such that its `stdin` is the same as `pipefd[0]`.  You use the `dup()`/`close()` trick to renumber the file descriptors just before executing the commands so that they become `0` (`stdin`) or `1` (`stdout`).

For piping together three programs, you will have two pipes.  The middle program will be reading from the first one and writing to the second one.

Comment: I'd really like to see a runnable C example of this.

Answer (score 0):

The shell handles all the grunt work with setting up the pipes and creating processes, so you don't have to worry about that at all. From your programs point of view, this is normal input from `stdin`, which means you can use the normal input function such as `scanf` or `fread` from `stdin`.