# Another Linux command output (Piped) as input to my C program

Tags: c, pipe

I'm now working on a small C program in Linux. Let me explain you what I want to do with a sample Linux command below

```
ls | grep hello
```

The above command is executed in the below passion (Let me know if I've got this wrong)

1. ls command will be executed first
2. Output will be given to grep command which will again generate output by matching "hello"

Now I would like to write a C program which takes the piped output of one command as input. Means, In the similar passion of how "grep" program was able to get the input from ls command (in my example above).

Similar question has been asked by another user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032323/piping-the-output-of-one-command-as-input-to-another-command), but for some reason this thread has been marked as "Not a valid question"

I initially thought we can get this as a command line argument to C program. But this is not the case.

Comment: Unix pipes work via [`STDIN` and `STDOUT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). You just need to read _standard in_ to get your input, and write to _standard out_ to give your output.

Comment: Thanks DaoWen - I've implemented it by reading the input from STDIN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pipe the output from one command into another, that output will be available on the receiving process's standard input (stdin).

You can access it using the usual `scanf` or `fread` functions. `scanf` and the like operate on stdin by default (in the same way that `printf` operates on stdout by default; in the absence of a pipe, stdin is attached to the terminal), and the C standard library provides a [`FILE *stdin`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html) for functions like `fread` that read from a FILE stream.

POSIX also provides a `STDIN_FILENO` macro in `unistd.h`, for functions that operate one file descriptors instead. This will essentially always be 0, but it's bad form to rely on that being the case.

Comment: Thanks - I've just implemented the program using "scanf" which had done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If fact, `ls` and `grep` starts at the same time.

`ls | grep hello` means, use `ls`'s standard output as `grep`'s standard input. `ls` write results to standard output, `grep` waits and reads any output from standard input at once.

Still have doubts? Do an experiment. run

`find / | grep usr`

*`find /` will list all files on the computer, it should take a lot of time.*

If `ls` runs first, then OS gives the output to `grep`, we should wait a long time with blank screen until `find` finished and `grep` started. But, we can see the results at once, that's a proof for that.

Comment: While true, this doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't answer the question. I wanted to descript that with a comment, but I want to make it more readable...